# How to access Spring context from a depending project?

Tags: java, spring, classpath, applicationcontext

Suppose I have two projects:

```
ProjectA and ProjectB
ProjectA depends on ProjectB
```

And I have a **context.xml** locates at **ProjectB/target/test-classes/context.xml**. Now I need to loat the context from ProjectA. In projectB I have an accesser class:

```
Class ContextAccessor{
    ApplicationContext context = new
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml");

    public static ApplicationContext getContext(){
        return context;
    }
}
```

While in ProjectA, I'm trying to get the context using:

```
ContextAccessor.getContext();
```

but it throws an exception with message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException     parsing XML document from class path resource [context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
at
```

Please give suggestions. Appreciation.

Comment: Have you added the classes and resources from projectB to the classpath of projectA?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: No. What can I do if I don't want to change the project configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this issue by using:

```
Class ContextAccessor{
    ApplicationContext context = new
        FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().
        getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());

    public static ApplicationContext getContext(){
        return context;
    }
}
```

Assuming the context is at **ProjectB/target/classes/context.xml**

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that ProjectB (i suppose it's packaged as a jar) in ProjectA's classpath. refer [here](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html) if you are using Maven, to understand how this can be done.

Once it's in class path you should be able create a context with the code given above. Also make sure the location of context.xml is correctly passed to the constructor, refer to JavaDoc for [ClassPathXmlApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html).

Comment: ProjectB is in ProjectA's dependencies but not classPath. Is there a walkaround without change the project configuration?

Comment: I cant think of any other way through which you can access the pom file without bringing the ProjectB jar in ProjectA's classpath. 

but why cant you make changes to pom configuration??

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't added ProjectB in project dependencies of ProjectA. Please add it and try again.

Comment: I have checked the pom. ProjectB does exist in ProjectA's dependencies. Otherwise I should not be able to use ContextAccessor, right?